# AWS: How to find out which step function is being called by API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, gateway

New to AWS and to coding in general here.
Please see attached photo. This API calls an AWS Step Function. How can I find out which step function this API calls?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfVLC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't define it on this screen, and because of that you can't tell which step function will be called. The function `name` and `stateMachineArn` will be passed as parameters to the request to an API.

See an example and explanation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html#api-gateway-step-2) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html)